# rJava not Installing in AIX

Tags: java, r, aix, rjava

I am trying to install `rJava` in AIX.
But it fails with following error:

```
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program /usr/java6_64/jre/bin/java because of the following errors:
        0509-150   Dependent module /opt/app/dev/iQueue/OpenR/lib/libiconv.a(shr4_64.o) could not be loaded.
        0509-152   Member shr4_64.o is not found in archive
```

My LIBPATH is set to :

```
:/opt/app/dev/iQueue/OpenR/lib $echo $LIBPATH
/usr/lib
```

But still it is looking for `libiconv.a` in /opt/app/dev/iQueue/OpenR/lib/

My Path is:

```
export PATH=/usr/lib:$PATH:/usr/lib:/opt/app/dev/iQueue/OpenR_install/bin:/opt/IBM/xlc/13.1.0/bin:/opt/IBM/xlf/15.1.0/bin:/usr/java6_64/bin/java:/opt/IBM/xlC/13.1.0/bin
export LIBPATH=/usr/lib
export LIBICONV=/opt/app/dev/iQueue/OpenR
export CC="xlc -lpthread"
export CXX="xlc++ -lpthread"
export FC="xlf -lpthread"
export F77="xlf -lpthread"
export CFLAGS="-qarch=auto -qcache=auto -qtune=auto -O3 -qstrict -ma"
export FFLAGS="-qarch=auto -qcache=auto -qtune=auto -O3 -qstrict"
export FCFLAGS="-qarch=auto -qcache=auto -qtune=auto -O3 -qstrict"
export CXXFLAGS="-qarch=auto -qcache=auto -qtune=auto -O3 -qstrict"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$LIBICONV/include -I/usr/lpp/X11/include/X11"
export LDFLAGS="-L$LIBICONV/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib"
export ODBC_INCLUDE=$/opt/app/dev/iQueue/ODBC/include
export ODBC_LIBS=$/opt/app/dev/iQueue/ODBC/lib
export AR="ar -X64"
```

Can someone help me installing `rJava` for R in AIX 6.1

Comment: What gives `R CMD javareconf`?

Comment: I dont have root Acces - when i tried `R CMD javareconf -e` , it gave the same error - which i posted in the question

Comment: It seems to be a specific [AIX problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604721/java-not-working-in-aix)

Comment: I have Gone through the link and changed my LIBPATH , but still its not woking.

Comment: (I know it is late)
Script `rJava` might change LIBPATH making the loader to find `/opt/app/dev/iQueue/OpenR/lib/libiconv.a` instead of `/usr/lib/libiconv.a`